# Compare two variables

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a scenario to compare two variables in component html file. for example

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
    <td style="width: 20%">
        <input type="text" name="FirstName" value={{item.id}} [disabled]="!isEditable && item.id == id">
    </td>
     <td><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="showAsEditable(item);"></i></td>
</tr>
```

ts:

```
filterData;
id : string;
isEditable = false;

showAsEditable(temp){           
    this.isEditable = true;
    this.id = temp.id;
}
```

In the above example, i want compare two variables as

```
[disabled]="!isEditable && item.id == id"
```

but this is not actually comparing properly, how to compare this two different vartiabls.

Comment: You mean your item is never editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the logic in comparison is a bit confusing here.

What you compare here is:

> if **NOT EDITABLE** and **ITEM IS WHAT I WANT** then **disabled**

But you want

> if **NOT**( **IS EDITABLE**  and **ITEM IS WHAT I WANT**) then **disabled**

So you can wrap with parenthesis like:

```
[disabled]="!(isEditable && item.id == id)"
```